# Pourquoi y a-t-il une différence d'orthographe entre « inflexion » et « inflection » ?

Tags: anglais, orthographe

« inflexion » et « inflection ». Ils se prononcent tous deux de la même façon. En anglais il s'écrit avec « *ct* ». Pourquoi la différence ?

Comment: C'est un problème de connexion entre les deux mots :-)

Comment: Il faut constater qu'en anglais la mode littéraire était d'utiliser *x* en place de *ct* pour ces mots jusqu'à très récemment. J'ai un livre anglais des années 1970 où le mot *connexion* est écrit avec un *x*. [Voir aussi ceci](https://www.etymonline.com/word/connection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bon! Comme l'a probablement dit César en un moment de déprime : J'arrête avec les commentaires! ;-) C'est juste pas possible.

Le latin connaît **deux** termes différents :

1/ INFLE**CT**ERE : infinitif d'un [**Verbe** appartenant au 1er type de conjugaison](http://www.dicolatin.com/XY/LAK/0/INFLECTERE/index.htm) et employé au sens de *plier, fléchir* (et de quelques autres aussi, cf bas de page du lien)

2/ INFLE**X**IO : [**Nom** féminin](http://www.dicolatin.com/FR/LAK/0/INFLEXIO/index.htm) employé d'abord pour désigner l'action de fléchir (la flexion) puis, plus tard, par les grammairiens pour leur cuisine.

Le français a (XIVè), pour son verbe *infléchir*, emprunté le verbe latin et pour son substantif *inflexion* emprunté le substantif latin.

L'anglais adopte initialement la même démarche (d'où la survivance d'*inflexion* en anglais dans le texte)

---

<sub>Le français conservera par la suite cette distinction, l'anglais préféra simplifier en alignant son substantif sur son verbe au point qu'on pourrait dire que l'*inflection* substantif anglais n'est pas emprunté au latin mais dérive immédiatement du verbe anglais *to inflect*, lui-même dérivant du verbe latin *inflectere*.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

En anglais on trouve les deux formes, inflection et inflexion (dictionnaire d'Oxford, en particulier en anglais britannique), bien que la première soit la plus courante (constatation personnelle) .
D'après le dictionnaire d'Oxford « inflection » provient du vieux français *inflexion* ou du latin *inflexio(n-)*, qui provient de *inflex-*<sup>1</sup> qui est la racine du participe passé de *inflectere*

Il semble donc qu'en anglais il y ait finalement eu une préférence pour la forme inspirée du participe passé et qu'en français le nom ou le verbe ait décidé de l'orthographe.

C'est un schéma orthographique que l'on retrouve dans d'autres mots anglais avec leur correspondance en français, par exemple « connection/connexion ».

1  <sub>« *inflex-* » est ce que l'on trouve dans l'étymologie fournie par le dictionnaire d'Oxford, mais selon les commentaires de aCOSwt, pour une raison quelconque (possiblement une approche différente à l'étymologie adoptée par les lexicographes d'Oxford) cela ne correspond pas à ce que l'on doit trouver dans une étymologie française qui ne reconnait que la forme « inflect- » ; les francophones devront donc lire « inflect- » à la place de « inflex- ».</sub>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85876/discussion-between-acoswt-and-lph).